# Facing issue with for loop

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm

I am trying to get this function to read an input file and output the lines from the input file into a new file. Pycharm keeps saying 'item' is not being used or it was used in the first for loop. I don't see why 'item' is a problem. It also won't create the new file.

```
input_list = 'persist_output_input_file_test.txt'

def persist_output(input_list):
    input_file = open(input_list, 'rb')
    lines = input_file.readlines()
    input_file.close()
    for item in input_list:
        write_new_file = open('output_word.txt', 'wb')
        for item in lines:
            print>>input_list, item
        write_new_file.close()
```

Comment: Where exactly do you think you've used `item` in `for item in input_list:` body? You've shadowed that name with another value in line: `for item in lines:`, and before that line `item` was never used.

Comment: Do not use the >> operator. That's a bitshifting operator in Python, and not the extraction operator like you get in C++.  It will try to rightshift `print` by however many bytes you say on the right - which is absurd, and the program will rightly throw an error.

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Also PyCharm told you that using a stream operator from C++ `>>` was ok? And *even in c++* it's `cout <<`

Answer (score 0):

You have a few things going wrong in your program.

1. `input_list` seems to be a string denoting the name of a file. Currently you are iterating over the characters in the string with `for item in input_list`.
2. You shadow the already created variable `item` in your second `for` loop. I recommend you change that.
3. In Python, depending on which version you use, the correct syntax for printing a statement to the screen is `print text`(Python 2) or `print(text)`(Python 3). Unlike c++'s `std::cout << text << endl;`. `<<` and `>>` are actually bit wise operators in Python that shift the bits either to the left or to the right.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues in your implementation. Refer the following code for what you intend to do:

```
def persist_output(input_list):
    input_file = open(input_list, 'rb')
    lines = input_file.readlines()
    write_new_file = open('output_word.txt', 'wb')
    input_file.close()
    for item in lines:
        print item
        write_new_file.write(item);
```

The issues with your earlier implementation are as follows:

1. In the first loop you are iterating in the input file name. If you intend to keep `input_list` a list of input files to be read, then you will also have to open them. Right now, the loop iterates through the characters in the input file name.
2. You are opening the output file in a loop. So, Only the last write operation will be successful. You would have to move the the file opening operation outside the loop(*Ref: above code snippet*) or edit the mode to 'append'. This can be done as follows:

   write_new_file = open('output_word.txt', 'a')
3. There is a syntax error with the way you are using `print` command.

Comment: This isn't very helpful to a beginner who is just learning and hasn't grasped the `print` statement yet. Just giving him code that compiles with no explanation is not constructive.

Answer (score -1):

```
f=open('yourfilename','r').read()
f1=f.split('\n')
p=open('outputfilename','w')
for i in range (len(f1)):
    p.write(str(f1[i])+'\n')
p.close()
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Although this seems to solve the OP’s problem, a brief explanation on *why* it does so would be great.